# Which way are rows and columns in a numpy 2-d array used as a matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

When using a numpy array as a matrix, in which order are rows and columns?

For example:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Is `[1, 2, 3]` the first row or the first column?

I cannot find this information in the documentation, perhaps because the answer is too obvious.

Comment: The order is the obvious one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[1, 2, 3]` is the first row.

The examples in [numpy ndarray documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#the-n-dimensional-array-ndarray) actually gives you some hints:

> ````py
> >>> x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], np.int32)
>
> >>> # The element of x in the *second* row, *third* column, namely, 6.
> >>> x[1, 2] ```
> ````